# Remove extra paragraph after table pasted from Excel to Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a code for writing Word documents from Excel. Currently after each table pasted to Word from Excel empty line appears in Word document. I was thinking is it possible to remove one line after each table pasted or are there any better suggestions?

My current code:

```
Set xlRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Document").Range("G3", ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Document").Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

Set wdRng = .Range.Characters.Last

For Each Cell In xlRng
    wdRng.InsertAfter vbCr & Cell.Offset(0, -5).Text
    Select Case LCase(Cell.Value)

    Case "table6"
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tables").Range("B817:C820").Copy
        With wdRng
        Set rngPara = .Paragraphs.Last.Range
        rngPara.Style = "Data"
        rngPara.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
        .Tables(.Tables.Count).Range.Paragraphs.Indent
        .Font.Hidden = 0
        '.Range.Paragraphs(-1).Range.Delete
        Set rngPara = Nothing
        End With

    End Select
Next Cell
```

I have tried to use `.Range.Paragraphs(-1).Range.Delete` (commented out in my code) without success. What is the correct command for that kind of operation?

Even solution for removing previous paragraph would help. I can create own case for it and perform this command after each table.

---

**EDIT:**

Here is full code if somebody want to test:

```
Sub opentemplateWord()
    Dim Paragraphe As Object, WordApp As Object, WordDoc As Object
    Dim wSystem As Worksheet
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim wdRng As Object 'Word.Range
    Dim xlRng As Excel.Range
    Dim tempFolderPath As String
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim fileTitle As String
    Dim rngPara As Object

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandlerEndExecution

    Set wSystem = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Templates")

    Dim File: File = Environ("Temp") & "\" & "Document_template" & ".docx"
    'creationsession Word
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    'word ll be close to run
    WordApp.Visible = False
    'open the file .doc
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(File)

    With WordDoc

    Set xlRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Document").Range("G3", ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Document").Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    Set wdRng = .Range.Characters.Last

    For Each Cell In xlRng
        wdRng.InsertAfter vbCr & Cell.Offset(0, -5).Text
        Select Case LCase(Cell.Value)

    Case "title"
        wdRng.Paragraphs.Last.Style = .Styles("Title")

    Case "main"
        wdRng.Paragraphs.Last.Style = .Styles("Heading 2")

    Case "empty"
         wdRng.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Delete

    Case "pagebreak"
        wdRng.Paragraphs.Last.Range.InsertBreak Type:=7 'wdPageBreak

        Case "table6"
          ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tables").Range("B817:C820").Copy
            With wdRng
            Set rngPara = .Paragraphs.Last.Range
            rngPara.Style = "Data"
            rngPara.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
            .Tables(.Tables.Count).Range.Paragraphs.Indent
            .Font.Hidden = 0
            '.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Delete
            Set rngPara = Nothing
            End With

        End Select
    Next Cell

        WordDoc.SaveAs2 Environ$("Temp") & "\" & _
                "Test" & ".docx"

    End With

    WordDoc.Close
    WordApp.Quit
    Set WordDoc = Nothing
    Set WordApp = Nothing

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandlerEndExecution:

    WordDoc.Close
    WordApp.Quit
    Set WordDoc = Nothing
    Set WordApp = Nothing

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Your example is missing some key elements. The `Set wdRng = .Range.Characters.Last` is clearly part of a `With` block, but that isn't shown. Even when I added the Microsoft Word 15.0 Object Library reference, the `.PasteExcelTable` gives an error as "Method or Data Member Not Found". Plus, you're missing the `Select Case Cell` part of the `Select` statement above the `Case` line. Your example code isn't close to compiling to help check on the problem. Can you use `Option Explicit` and update your code please.

Comment: @PeterT I have added full code

Comment: When a table is created in Word it must always be followed by a paragraph. As you are pasting the table into the last paragraph of the document you will be left with an empty paragraph that cannot be deleted.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt As true as that may be, the OP is also inserting content after the table. The OP's code leaves an unwanted empty paragraph between the table and that other content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating another question, use the following code instead of the code from my previous answer.

After:

```
Next Cell
```

Insert:

```
Dim t As Long
With WordDoc
  For t = 1 To .Tables.Count
    Set wdRng = .Tables(t).Range.Characters.Last.Next
    If wdRng.End < .Range.End Then
      If wdRng.Text = vbCr Then wdRng.Delete
    End If
  Next
End With
```

Comment: I am currently testing this one

Comment: Just for others... In my case it should be `With WordDoc`, not  `With ActiveDocument`. This is working solution! I hope macropod will continue to leave his footprint in MS Word VBA history.

Answer (score 1):

After:

```
Set wdRng = .Range.Characters.Last
```

Insert:

```
wdRng.InsertAfter vbCr
```

Change:

```
wdRng.InsertAfter vbCr & Cell.Offset(0, -5).Text
```

To:

```
wdRng.InsertAfter Cell.Offset(0, -5).Text & vbCr
```

After:

```
Next Cell
```

Insert:

```
Do While wdRng.Characters.Last.Previous = vbCr
  wdRng.Characters.Last.Previous.Delete
Loop
```

Comment: I knew that macropod is there to help. This is almost there. Current solution is messing up headers, so it is performing "remove of paragraph" for each line in headers. This is making headers "jump up" and texts below headers are becoming "headers". I am currently trying to understand what have to be changed so it will perform "remove of paragraph" only after each table. I have added more cases to my original question.

Comment: «Current solution is messing up headers, so it is performing "remove of paragraph" for each line in headers. This is making headers "jump up" and texts below headers are becoming "headers" ... I have added more cases to my original question.» Kindly stop moving the goal posts. Your original post said nothing about those other factors. The answer I posted works for the problem as originally put.

Comment: Ok, then I will create another one. Thank you for this!